# Comparing date values using if statement in php

Tags: php, html, date

I want to compare 2 date values and if it meets the conditions, let it display a particular value. I used the code below, but it's not working. It looks like I am not getting the date comparison well.

What i want to achieve is this. If date1 is more than 3 months or date2 is greater than 6 months let it display something, but if its not let it display another.

I am using an if statement here.

```
<?php

$levcon = $row_rsRecord['level'];
$semcon = $row_rsCourse['semester'];
$d = $row_rsCourse['date'];
$dae = strtotime($row_rsCourse['date']);
$dae1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+3 months", $dae));
$daet = strtotime($row_rsCourse['date']);
$daet1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+6 months", $daet));

if(($semcon == 1) && ($dae1 < $d) || ($semcon == 2) && ($daet1 < $d) ) { ?>
<a href="printout.php">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-danger"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-suitcase fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
</a>

<?php } else { ?>

<a href="coursereg.php">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-danger"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-suitcase fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
</a>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your grouping clauses are non-sensical; I imagine you meant that the first two group and the two groups are grouped as well, so the middle `||` doesn't logically conflict with the other conditions?

Comment: What is `$row_rsCourse['date']`? Also,  can you explain what you mean by **if date1 is more than 3 months or date2 is greater than 6 months** i.e. if `date1` is more than 3 months from what?

Answer (score 0):

I can't solve the entire issue as I find dae, dae1, daet and daet1 rather confusing, and I don't know what `$row_rsCourse['date']` contains?

I've tried cleaning it up a bit though.

1. Renamed some of the variables to something a bit more descriptive of what they are.
2. $dae and $daet are the same, so I removed one of them, and renamed the remaining one dateUnix as it's a unix time representation of whatever's in `$row_rsCourse['date']`.
3. I joined the two clauses of the if statement into a single  block, using `echo` to print the HTML in between.
4. If it only needs to check if it's greater than 6 and otherwise do something else one might as well only check for greater than 6 and have an else clause handle the other cases. For now I split the two conditions into if and elseif, assuming nothing should be done if both are false.
5. < and > have greater [operator precedence](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than &&, || and ==, so some of the parentheses in the if statement don't need to be there.

> ```
> <?php 
> $levcon = $row_rsRecord['level'];
> $semcon = $row_rsCourse['semester'];
> $date = $row_rsCourse['date'];
> $dateUnix = strtotime($date);
> $threeMonths = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+3 months", $dateUnix));
> $sixMonths = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+6 months", $dateUnix));
>
> if ($semcon == 1 && $sixMonths < $date) {
>   echo '<a href="printout.php"><span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
>       <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-danger"></i>
>       <i class="fa fa-suitcase fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
>   </span></a>';
> }
> elseif ($semcon == 2 && $threeMonths < $date) {
>   echo '<a href="coursereg.php"><span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
>     <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-danger"></i>
>     <i class="fa fa-suitcase fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
>   </span></a>';
> }
> ?>
> ```

I have not done this because I don't completely understand your issue/variables, but you should call strtotime on all those dates as the last step before comparing them.